# ExpressJS / MYSQL / Prisma - Save DB' entities changes

Tags: mysql, express, middleware, prisma

I'm looking for a way to save database entities changes for some entities. I mean I need to save in a database table all changes that are done on some tables (add, modify / delete) with ability to track user which did the change.

I'm working on NextJS with a custom ExpressJS server and MYSQL database were I use Prisma as ORM. I think it's maybe possible to write an ExpressJS middleware but I have yet no idea how to do it and asking myself if any library already exist.

Usually I work on PHP Symfony and used to manage this [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/current/index.html) which is great and works as expected. But my current project is a Typescript project only with Express/NextJS/React/Prisma/MYSQL.

Any feedback from your knowledge will be very appreciate.

Thank's in advance.

Regards,

Gulivert

EDIT: My current API which has to be moved to Express/NextJS is still running on Symfony and the table where all changes is logged looks like this :

```json
{
    "id": 59807,
    "user": "ccba6ad2-0ae8-11ec-813f-0242c0a84005",
    "patient": "84c3ef66-548a-11ea-8425-0242ac140002",
    "action": "update",
    "logged_at": "2021-11-02 17:55:09",
    "object_id": "84c3ef66-548a-11ea-8425-0242ac140002",
    "object_class": "App\\Entity\\Patient",
    "version": 5,
    "data": "a:2:{s:10:\"birth_name\";s:2:\"--\";s:10:\"profession\";s:2:\"--\";}",
    "username": "johndoe",
    "object_name": "patient",
    "description": null
  }
```

Explanation about database columns:

- user => relation to user table
- patient => relation to patient table
- action => can be "create"/"update"/delete"
- logged_at => date time where the change was done
- object_id => entity row ID where an entity get a change
- object_class => the entity updated
- version => how many time the object was change
- data => all data changed during the modification
- username => the username of logged user did the change
- object_name => a string to identify the object modified without
- using the namespace of object_class
- description => a value that can be update on some specific change * during usually the action delete to keep a trace what was deleted for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [prisma middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) useful for this.

Check out the example with [session data middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware/session-data-middleware) which is somewhat similar to what you're doing.

For your use-case the middleware might look like something like this:

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const contextLanguage = 'en-us' // Session state

prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
// you can find all possible params.action values in the `PrismaAction` type in `.prisma/client/index.d.ts`. 
  if (params.model == '_modelWhereChangeIsTracked_' && (params.action == 'create' || params.action == "update")) {
    // business logic to create an entry into the change logging table using session data of the user. 
  }

  return next(params)
})

// this will trigger the middleware 
const create = await prisma._modelWhereChangeIsTracked_.create({
  data: {
    foo: "bar" 
  },
})
```

However, do note that there are some [performance considerations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware#performance-and-appropriate-use-cases) when using Prisma middleware.

You can also create [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for the routes where you anticipate changes that need to be logged in the change table. Personally, I would *prefer this approach* in most cases, especially if the number of API routes where changes need to be logged is known in advance and limited in number.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sounds perfect, I did not notice about Prisma middleware before (I'm new with this). As more and less all datable must be tracked for changes, I would prefer to use Prisma middleware than express middleware. The logic is always the same for all tracked table. Again thank's for your help.

Comment: Welcome! If you're tracking changes to a ton of tables, then I would also agree that Prisma middleware seems like the more manageable solution.

Comment: By the way, you can find all possible params.action values in the `PrismaAction` type in `.prisma/client/index.d.ts`.